# Using Protobuf to process a config file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm relatively new to Protobufs and I was wondering how I would use it to process a list of structures.

Lets say I have a configuration file that looks like this:

```
Bucket{
    name = "A";
    path = "~/Document/...";
    traffic = 5;
}
Bucket{
    name = "B";
    path = "~/Document/...";
    traffic = 6;
}
Bucket{
    name = "C";
    path = "~/Document/...";
    traffic = 7;
}
```

etc etc.

So I am using a protobuf to essentially structure this for ease of use later in  Java. I'm essentially trying to make a map in a map (a protobuf to help find the correct bucket, and then another map to obtain member attributes inside the bucket).

```
option java_outer_classname = "Buckets";

message Bucket {
    required string name = 1;
    required string path = 2;
    optional int32 traffic = 3;
}

message BucketList {
    required Bucket bucket = 1;
}
```

I'm confused on how I would link the two, as in, how would I pass the configuration file into the protobuf methods (after it compiles into a java class) and use to to access the bucket member to do stuff like say get the path from the bucket with the name A?

Thank you!

Comment: In your `BucketList` message, did you mean to say `repeated` instead of `required`?

Comment: I did. I realized that was causing me huge problems. Right now, I'm doing a work around on this issue. Once I figure it out, I'll post the solution here.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly acceptable to use Protobuf as a mechanism to declare and parse a text configuration file.  However, one must keep in mind that Protobuf's purpose is the declare the format of the file, be it plain text or its binary wire format.  Higher level semantic constraints need to be enforced in custom application code, once the configuration has been read.

Answer (score -1):

You've got the wrong idea of what protobuf is used for, it is a data interchange library which means its used to encode and exchange data between programs. It was never meant to be used for configuration and doesn't have a way to read a text-based definition of the data since it deals with binary files.

Looking at your config format you have two options:

1. The format you've chosen looks a lot like HOCON, so https://github.com/typesafehub/config should be able to read it and provide a readable config object with a small amount of editing.
2. If you want a type-safe config (defining the structure of the config as an actual java object) you will need to use some other format which supports deserialization to object. A JSON configuration can be read into objects using libraries like https://github.com/google/gson or https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Er, what? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat Protocol buffers are totally used for configuration.

Comment: I thought protobuf would be better to use for large data sets? (I could be completely wrong about this).

Comment: @LouisWasserman TIL, although the documentation appears to be extremely sparse.

Comment: @AkshayShukla Besides the fact that protobuf has a text format I was unaware of, the strength of protobuf lies in its binary representation, which is extremely compact and quick, thus suitable for datasets. However a dataset if not a config and they require different approaches/ways to manage them.